# sed align all lines to last line in a file Bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, alignment

I have a files with below lines

```
Dev_Campaign_1873.rpm
Dev_Campaign_1987.rpm
Dev_Campaign_9876.rpm
http://52.30.241.107:8081/artifactory/api/storage/adifact
```

Trying to get the output to a file as below using sed or any other command

```
http://52.30.241.107:8081/artifactory/api/storage/adifact/Dev_Campaign_1873.rpm
http://52.30.241.107:8081/artifactory/api/storage/adifact/Dev_Campaign_1987.rpm
http://52.30.241.107:8081/artifactory/api/storage/adifact/Dev_Campaign_9876.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed script:
It is very hackish and relies on two things: text doesn't contain symbol '|' and only last line begins with 'http:'.

```
:again
${
s/\n/|/g
# to include first part too
s/^/|/
:next
# modify last non processed part
s/\(.*\)|\([^|]\+\)|\(.*\)\(http:.*\)/\1|\4\/\2\n\3\4/
t next
# remove unneeded guard
s/^|//
# remove prefix
s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]\+\)/\1/
b end
}
N
b again
:end
```

How does it work?

Suppose, that we have this input:

```
aaa
bbb
http://zzz
```

First, the script combines all lines from file into internal buffer:

```
:again
${
    # Here internal buffer will be processed
    b end
}
N
b again
:end
```

It's very common pattern in my scripts, when sed cannot process text by line
and input isn't very big. Starting from first line script doesn't interupt and
just read next line ('N') into buffer till the end.

When it get last line ('$') it can process further. And when it finished it
stops ('b end'). One can not to use difinite label to reach end, just 'b' will
work too, but I prefer clarity.

So, now in internal buffer is this text:

```
aaa\nbbb\nhttp://zzz
```

Next it separates lines with symbol '|' instead of '\n':

```
s/\n/|/g
# to include first part too
s/^/|/

|aaa|bbb|http://zzz
```

Then it tries to find this pattern

```
...|text|.....http://...
```

and change it to this

```
...|http://...text\n.....http://...
```

Due to greeding nature of used regex, the substitution happens from the end to
start of string, on each step eliminating one symbol '|':

```
Initial state of buffer:
|aaa|bbb|http://zzz

After first step:
|aaa|http://zzz/bbb\nhttp://zzz

After second step:
|http://zzz/aaa\nhttp://zzz/bbb\nhttp://zzz
```

Loop was organized with the help of command 't next'. It jumps to label 'next'
if last substitution was successful.

Next it removes unneeded guard '|' at the start of line:

```
s/^|//

http://zzz/aaa\nhttp://zzz/bbb\nhttp://zzz
```

And last line:

```
s/\(.*\n\)\([^\n]\+\)/\1/

http://zzz/aaa\nhttp://zzz/bbb
```

So, when it finally print buffer, you'll get this:

```
http://zzz/aaa
http://zzz/bbb
```